# Why is my code working with smaller values, but does not scale with larger numbers?

Tags: vba

EDIT: People pointed out that I was using Integer instead of Long...when I changed it, the formula returned 0...so it is still failing.

I have the following code

```
Public Function BreakEven(currenttier As Double, currentrate As Double, nexttier As Double, nextrate As Double) As Double


Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

x = currentrate * currenttier
y = nexttier * nextrate

If currenttier >= nexttier Then

   MsgBox "currenttier must be less than nexttier"


Else

    Do Until (x = y)


       currenttier = currenttier + 1
       x = currentrate * currenttier

    Loop

End If

BreakEven = currenttier

End Function
```

The purpose is to find the breakeven point in a cost structure, where a certain value (currenttier and nexttier) gives a corresponding interest rate. The interest rate changes when you reach the next tier...this calculates at what point in the lower tier, are you better off paying for the next tier (to reap the benefit of the 2nd tiers interest rate)

This code works fine when I use the numbers 100,000 and 200,000 (rates, but fails when it is upgraded to 1.5 mil to 2 mil (returns #VALUE)....I've tried changing the Do Until from X=y to include a wider margin for error (+-100)...yet it still seems to fail. Any ideas as to why.

The If statement is so that the loop doesn't enter an infinite loop and break excel.

Comment: What rates are you using with 100K/200K and 1.5M/2.0M?  It's easier to reproduce the problem with all the inputs.

Comment: Seldom you have exact matches as x=y. You may have to use Do Until ABS(x-y)<= 0.001 or whatever.

Comment: in your case you have to do untile x>y. Separately, from a pure finance sense, currenttier may be a wrong terminology. "tier" means a slab i.e. boundary. you can be anywhere in the slab and where you are will be usually be an "amount" or a "borrowing" or a "principal". Next tier is the lower boundary of the next slab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Public Function BreakEven(currenttier As Double, currentrate As Double, nexttier As Double, nextrate As Double) As Double

Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

x = currentrate * currenttier
y = nexttier * nextrate

If currenttier >= nexttier Then

   MsgBox "currenttier must be less than nexttier"
   Exit Function
   ---- or any other action----
Else

   Do while x < y
       currenttier = currenttier + 1
       x = currentrate * currenttier
   Loop

End If

BreakEven = currenttier

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

**VBA integers are 16 bit** with a maximum value of 32767. I kid you not!

Use a `Long` instead. This will be good for just over 2 billion.

Comment: I changed it to Long, but still returned 0...I am getting the "Calculation is Incomplete" error when I try saving the code...so it is still in the loop.

to clarify: I did successfully save the Long change, and reran the code...the error popped up after I tried saving it again

Answer (score 2):

Integer max value is  2,147,483,647 
so when you multiply 2 million by 1.5 mil for example the number goes beyond that.
Try using Big INt or Long

Comment: Thank you, the purpose of using Integer was to make all the numbers round to a whole number ( so that i do not have to find the excact decimals to get them to have them equal each other)

Comment: @Elgert: you're essentially correct but the maximum value of a VBA integer is not the value you say it is. Please fix and upvote: I only answered this myself due to this inaccuracy.

Comment: well i assumed the standard 32 bit integer used in many programming languages. Thank you for correcting me.